# How to cancel a routed event?

Tags: wpf, events, checkbox

I have a WPF application, where when a user unchecks a checkbox, the application will prompt to confirm.  If the user chooses not to continue (cancel) is selected, i want to cancel the uncheck event.  In another word, i want the checkbox to remain checked.

How can i do that in WPF?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way is to use [Data Validation](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/wpf-sample-series-handling-and-reporting-wpf-data-binding-validation-errors-and-exceptions/) on your binding, where your "IsValid" function is whether the user answers Yes to the prompt.

**Update:** [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx) is pretty good too