# How to take action if user tries to check/uncheck a checkbox by keyboard or mouse?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I'm writing an app (WPF MVVM) and I need to prompt the user whenever he tries to chek/uncheck some checkbox (and other controls but I'll focus on checkbox for this post).
I need him to confirm via MessageBox whether he wants to continue with the action started by the checkbox, I already have that MessageBox question into the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event, but just now someone told me: what if they check/uncheck using the keyboard?

Is there an analog keyboard event that I can hook to the code I already have for the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event so the prompt is shown anytime they check/uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: This is what the CheckBox.CheckedEvent and CheckBox.UncheckedEvent are for.

Comment: The problem is that those 2 don't have a preview event...  And I don't want the associated property setter to run if the user declines the message box...

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855258/how-to-cancel-a-routed-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PreviewKeyDown/KeyUp event on the control that you can attach a `ICommand` to (for MVVM style) or wireup a code behind event (for non-MVVM).

The event can then display the message box and if needed you can then cancel the operation using:

```
if(e.Key == Key.Space)
{
    //TODO: processing for message box
    e.Handled = True
}
```

The above will mark the event chain as handled so further events in the pipeline do not get executed.

Note that `Key.Space` can be replaced with anything that you may want to capture or removed if you want to capture everything.

Comment: Yeah I found this solution yesterday while struggling with this issue, thanks anyway. I marked your response as the solution to this post.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you are using MVVM, I would suggest you handle this in the ViewModel (VM) class.

- Bind the IsChecked property on the CheckBox control to a property on the VM.
- In the VM, setup your logic for validating the checked value. You will not want to open a message box directly from the VM (that would tie the VM directly to a visual service). I would suggest creating a query service (as a C# interface) and implementing it with code that displays a MessageBox. Pass the service into the VM's constructor or have the VM pick up the service through a container (dependency injection or a global services container).
- If the query fails, don't change the value in the VM. The CheckBox in the view will maintain its previous state.

Comment: All changes in the UI that try to change the IsChecked property will try to update this property on the VM, so the UI issues will become irrelevant.